# Change an odoo datetime field where the date is coming from a .js file [Odoo 15]

Tags: javascript, python, odoo

I'm receiving in my field a DateTime from a .js file

```
context: {
    default_checkin: $(this).attr("date"),  # HERE
},
```

in this field

```
checkin = fields.Datetime("Expected-Date-Arrival", required=True,
        readonly=True, states= {"draft": [("readonly", False)]},
)
```

For some reason, I always get the time 00:53:59 and I want to modify the hour from the Python code, and the user can change it later. Maybe I have to use an @api but I don't know how to do it.

[image]

---

**EDIT**
I tried this code and It works, but then the field can't be changed by the user

```
checkin = fields.Datetime(
    "Expected-Date-Arrival",
    required=True,
    readonly=True,
    compute = "ckin",
    states= {"draft": [("readonly", False)]},
)

@api.onchange("checkin")
def ckin(self):
    for rec in self:
        date = rec.checkin
        date2 = date.strftime("%Y-%m-%d 17:00:00")
        rec.checkin = date2
```

Answer (score 0):

remove "readonly=True" from fields.Datetime